# Postfix not receiving mail. Helo command Unauthorized

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, postfix-mta

OS: `Ubuntu 12.04`

Mail version: `Postfix 2.9.6`

The sender is able to receive emails from us, but the emails are not showing up in our mailboxes, and I do not understand why.

```
Mar  2 08:24:16 mailsrv postfix/smtpd[30099]: connect from o1.ptr3680.wellable.co[192.254.121.56]
Mar  2 08:24:16 mailsrv postfix/smtpd[30099]: NOQUEUE: discard: RCPT from o1.ptr3680.wellable.co[192.254.121.56]: <o1.ptr3680.wellable.co>: Helo command Unauthorized-2015-240; from=<bounces+2978139-eb6d-redactedPerson=redacted.com@em3595.wellable.co> to=<redactedPerson@redacted.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<o1.ptr3680.wellable.co>
Mar  2 08:24:16 mailsrv postfix/smtpd[30099]: 65B019BB6DD: client=o1.ptr3680.wellable.co[192.254.121.56]
Mar  2 08:24:16 mailsrv postfix/smtpd[30099]: disconnect from o1.ptr3680.wellable.co[192.254.121.56]
```

I especially don't understand the `Helo command Unauthorized-2015-240` portion.

My main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
# myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
# delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/wc2_redacted.com.combined.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/wc2_redacted.com.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = mailsrvr.redacted.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost.$myhostname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/19 192.168.64.0/18 192.168.129.0/27 173.203.187.0/24 172.31.0.0/16 3.18.46.112/32 192.168.129.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
virtual_alias_domains = 
allow_percent_hack = no
swap_bangpath = no
mydomain = redacted.com
mynetworks_style = subnet
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unlisted_sender, permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated
delay_warning_time = 0h
maximal_queue_lifetime = 1d
bounce_queue_lifetime = 1d
proxy_read_maps = $canonical_maps $lmtp_generic_maps $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $mynetworks $recipient_bcc_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relay_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relocated_maps $sender_bcc_maps $sender_canonical_maps $smtp_generic_maps $smtpd_sender_login_maps $transport_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $smtpd_sender_restrictions
smtp_data_init_timeout = 240s
smtp_data_xfer_timeout = 600s
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =  reject_unlisted_sender, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
queue_run_delay = 300s
minimal_backoff_time = 300s
maximal_backoff_time = 4000s
enable_original_recipient = no
disable_vrfy_command = yes
home_mailbox = Maildir/
allow_min_user = no
message_size_limit = 104857600
virtual_minimum_uid = 1002
virtual_uid_maps = static:1002
virtual_gid_maps = static:1002
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/catchall_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_catchall_maps.cf
sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf
recipient_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_domain.cf
relay_domains = $mydestination, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/smtpd_sender_login_maps
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unlisted_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unlisted_recipient, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_whitelist, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_override, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/cidr_client_access, check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/rcp_access, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/wc2_redacted.com.combined.crt
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = ./dovecot-auth
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
smtp-amavis_destination_recipient_limit = 1
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 - that's out of support since years

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm aware of that. I don't have a choice. Not my call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! In `/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre`, there was this regex pattern:

`/.*\.co$/ DISCARD Unauthorized-2015-240`

which matched the message in the logs:

`Helo command Unauthorized-2015-240`

So I added regex to allow that specific domain:

`/.*o1.ptr3680.wellable.co$/ OK`

then reloaded Postfix and the emails were received upon trying again.